# Problems with UL in absolute or float, links not clickable

Tags: css, position, css-float, hyperlink, css-position

I have a javascript menu that I've produced using nested UL elements. When I set the nested UL to either use float with relative position, or to have absolute position with no float, the links in the li elements of that nested ul get jumbled up somehow. Some of them will be clickable, but not all.

Here is some sample code:

```
<ul class="top">
  <li class="first">
    <a href="somewhere" class="firstlink">The Link</a>
    <ul class="nested" id="menu_about">
        <li class="second"><a href="somewhere" class="secondlink">The Link</a></li>
        <li class="second"><a href="somewhere" class="secondlink">The Link</a></li>
        <li class="second"><a href="somewhere" class="secondlink">The Link</a></li>
        <li class="second"><a href="somewhere" class="secondlink">The Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#main_nav ul.top {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

#main_nav ul.top li.first {
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
}

#main_nav ul.top li.first a.firstlink, #main_nav ul.top li.first a.firstlinkactive {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 25px;
    background-image: url(/images/gray_back.png);
    padding-right: 10px;
    width: 140px;
}

#main_nav ul.top li.first a.firstlink:hover, #main_nav ul.top li.first a.firstlinkactive:hover {
    background-image: url(/images/red_back.png);
}

#main_nav ul.top li.first ul {
    left: 150px;
    text-align: left;
    background-image: url(/images/red_back.png);
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    top: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

#main_nav ul.top li.first ul.nested_hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#main_nav ul, #main_nav ul li, #main_nav ul li ul, #main_nav ul li ul li, #main_nav ul li ul li a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

If I set ul.nested to position:relative the links work again but it messes up the first-level li elements and stretches them to fill the space. Somehow setting position:absolute on the nested ul is causing problems with the links inside of it. I can also get the same behavior if I set position:relative and set float:left

Would appreciate some clarity on why float and absolute positioning causes this and a possible solution either in the html structuring, or css code.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I've learned when using lists, other than `float:left` on an LI (and clearing list type margin and padding) never style the LI. Only style the anchor and use `display:block` on the A tag.

Once you start styling a combination of LI and A things fall apart if you're not careful.

The basic pattern is this:

```
ul, li {
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
   list-style-typwe:none
}

ul {
   position: relative;
}

ul ul {
   position:absolute;
   top:___;
   left:___;
}

li a {
   display:block;
   ...your other styling ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks much, that's very helpful. Things are starting to play nicely now.